# Critical CPU utilization in Elastic BeanStalk instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have deployed a python application using the Flask framework to Elastic BeanStalk in ap-south-1a (Zone - mumbai, India).

I am also using an application load balancer with it. Below is the screenshot of the health status for EC2 instances:
[image]

This runs perfectly for 8-10 hours and then all of sudden in CPU utilization category user% starts tiuching 100% and helth status changed to severe. A screenshot is attached below:
[image]

Once I terminate the instance and create another one everything switches to normal.

Can anyone please help me with the reason it might be happening and what can be the way out.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: are the 2 applications identical and LB balances between the 2? What is the application? There is number of pointers how to run Flask apps in production (like disabling debug options).

Comment: Yes, both are the same. I have set the load balancer settings at min = 2 and max = 11 to balance incoming load traffic.

The debug option is disabled in the final deployment.